# Excel: Extract all partial matches from a two dimensional array and create a list with results

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with several cells containing text that includes the string "Link"in them. For example, the cells have text like ***Link 42, Link 126, Link 324*** etc. Now, these cells are scattered across the sheet among cells with other values. I want to make a neat vertical list of all the cells that have the word "Link" in them. I could find formulas that can handle this problem only if all the cells of interest are present in a single column. But, in my data such cells are all over the sheet, in multiple columns. Not sure how to deal with this. Could someone help me solve this problem.Apologies if I am asking for too much.

[image: This is how my search area and ideal outcomes look like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one has the Dynamic Array formulas then put this in the first cell:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",TRUE,B3:E12)&"</b></a>","//b[contains(.,'"&H1&"')]")
```

[image]

If not but one has TEXTJOIN then we can use INDEX() wrapper:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",TRUE,$B$3:$E$12)&"</b></a>","//b[contains(.,'"&$H$1&"')]"),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

this will need to be copied down the sheet.

If one does not have TEXTJOIN then VBA will be the best approach